# In Pandas, avoid memory thrashing when doing arithmetic on series with different indices?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory

Sometimes in pandas, I accidentally do math on two series with different indices. Like so:

```
some_data = my_large_dataframe[my_large_dataframe.outlier == False]

timeDelay = some_data.endTime - my_large_dataframe.startTime # oops! forgot to change my_large_dataframe to some_data
```

For some real data I'm using, since there are duplicate values in the index, this operation subtracts two series of length ~50,000 and outputs a series of length ~4,000,000. When I'm not so lucky, the quadratic behavior unstoppably thrashes my computer's memory before finally killing my Jupyter kernel.

This is very annoying. Is there a good way to avoid it? (Avoiding every + in favor of .add would also be annoying, and besides, wouldn't work when I plug my dfs into other people's functions.) Ideally a pandas setting to disable automatic realignment, or some Jupyter cell magic?

Comment: What about doing the arithmetic using numpy arrays which don't have index information but have different broadcasting rules causing an exception for your diff?